# Dev c++ crashes after fscanf is called in a loop

Tags: c

Please can someone tell me why the code bellow make dev c++ crashes ?

```
FILE* input;
int k=0;
char filename[]="";
int* Tab=NULL;
printf("Please specify the filename you want to open and read\n");

  scanf("%s",&filename);

//strcat(filename,".txt");
input=fopen(filename,"r");
if(input==NULL)
{
    printf("File open error");
  }

fscanf(input,"%d",&total);
Tab=malloc(total);
for(k=0;k<total;k++)// here is my problem 
{
    fscanf(input,"%d",&Tab[k]);
  }
```

The file gets open normally and the read was correct at first atempt then it sddenly started crashing  . the variable `total` can be read as well the next for loop is the problem .

Any help Please ?

Comment: ``char filename[]="";`` What makes you think, the entered filename will fit into this variable?

Comment: filename works fine , the debug gives a SIGSEGV signal ,segmentation problem . so i don't think the problem is with filename .

Comment: After you overwite (stack) memory, all bets of what will happen next in your code are off. And your filename thing does overwrite memory.

Comment: @user3121023 didn't work

Comment: @BitTickler Changed `char filename[]="";` to`char* filename;` but still does not work

Comment: Of course not. Try ``char filename[2048];`` and your odds will get much better as  long as your filename is shorter than 2048 characters. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c for more information on how you can do it.

Comment: @BitTickler aparently still not working .

Comment: But now it has N-1 reasons to crash ;)

Answer (score 2):

So the comments all show one thing: you think the compiler will handle memory for you.

Not so! In C, all memory handling must be done by you:

- in `char filename[]="";` you declare a 1-byte array (only the `'\0'`) but you think that the `scanf("%s",&filename);` will magically increase that to be able to hold a much longer filename. Not so! (And why the `&` on a character array?)
- in `Tab=malloc(total);` you think the compiler knows the size of the elements you want to store in `Tab`. Not so!

With every comment, you make a small change and "Darn! It still doesn't work!" Of course not, as you did not understand that the C compiler does not do memory handling for you. I suggest you read the book again on memory: read about global, static and automatic variables; read about arrays and strings and read about `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`.

(This is more a comment than a solution)